# Reading data from the vacuum gauge

Tags: python, hardware

I have a vacuum gauge Inficon CDG025D (PN:377-001 [GAUGE_DATASHEET](https://www.inficon.com/media/5506/download/SKY%C2%AE-CDG025D-0.1-...-1000-Torr---mbar.pdf?v=4&inline=true&language=en)).I am writing a program to read pressure from a gauge.
I found that I can read the data from the terminal, but I am not able to decode it.
The message frame is not correct with the documentation.
[RS232_COMUNICATION](https://www.inficon.com/media/4520/download/CDGxxxD-Communication-manual-RS232C.pdf?v=1&inline=true&language=en)

```
import serial
gauge = serial.Serial("COM8", 9600,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, timeout=1000, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE)
while(True):
    if gauge.in_waiting > 0:
        input_string= gauge.read(1)
        print(input_string)
        i += 1
        if i > 18:
            break
```

From RS232_COMUNICATION: The gauge continuously (approximately every 20 ms) transmits a nine byte send string without request.

The meter does not produce a frame with a length of 9 bytes.

```
b'|'
b'\xbf'
b'\xf7'
b'\x02'
b'\x01'
b'\xf7'
b'\xd7'
b'\x00'
b'|'   
b'\xbf'
b'\xf7'
b'\x02'
b'\x01'
b'\xf7'
b'\xd7'
b'\x00'
b'|'   
b'\xbf'
b'\xf7'
```

Data read shortly after the start of the gauge.

```
b'|'
b'\xbf'
b'\xf7'
b'\x03'
b'U'
b'\xf7'
b'-'
b'\x00'
b'|'
b'\xbf'
b'\xf7'
b'\x19'
b'\xef'
b'\xff'
b'\xf7'
b'\xdd'
b'|'
b'\xbf'
b'\xf7'
b'\x03'
b'\x97'
b'\xf7'
b'o'
b'\x00'
b'|'
b'\xbf'
b'\xf7'
b'\x01'
b'C'
b'\xf7'
b'\x19'
b'\x00'
```

I would need help on how to interpret this data.

Comment: Looks like 9 bytes to me `|1234567|1234567|123...`

Comment: But it does not match what should be sent in the RS232_COMMUNICATION documentation on page 3.
On page 6 (Example) there is an example of the frame as it should look like.

Comment: Mmmm... I would be inclined to ask the manufacturer's Tech Support.